# C# populating dropdownlist from database using selected item

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

there is probably a simple answer and I'm being dumb, but i need help and an outsider perspective. So I have 3 tables in a database: Category (CategoryID, Description), Manufacturer(ManufacturerID, Name), and Products(ProductID, CategoryID, ManufactureID, Model, and other crap). 
I need to populate Manufacturer DropDownList based on selection of Category DropDownList, but my code throws the "Column 'ManufacturerID' does not belong to table Table.", the spelling is correct, so I must be doing something wrong, but I cant figure out what it is. Any suggestions would be welcome, cause this is killing me. Here is my code.

```
public DataSet Manufacturers_Load_by_Category(int category)
    {
        dwas = new SqlDataAdapter("Manufacturers_Load_By_Category", conn); // stored procedure created in database
        ds = new DataSet();
        dwas.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dwas.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", category); 
        try
        {
            dwas.SelectCommand.Prepare();
            dwas.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return ds;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

this is stored procedure im using (it works, i checked it a 100 times)

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Manufacturers_Load_By_Category]
@category int
as
SELECT        Manufacturers.Name
FROM            Manufacturers INNER JOIN
              Products ON Manufacturers.ManufacturerID =      Products.ManufacturerID
WHERE        (Products.CategoryID = @category)
```

and finally my point of failure :(

```
protected void dlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cat = dlCategory.SelectedValue.ToString(); // get the value the user selected from the manufactuers drop down list
        Datalayer DL = new Datalayer(); // get access to the data layer
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int x = 0;
        //lblError.Visible = false;
        dlManufacturer.Items.Clear(); // clear all the values in the models drop down list
        dlManufacturer.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", "-1")); // reload the select option

        if (cat != "-1")
        {
            ds = DL.Manufacturers_Load_by_Category(Convert.ToInt32(cat));
            if (ds != null)
            {

                while (x < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                {
                    //exception is thrown here
                    // "Column 'ManufacturerID' does not belong to table Table."
                    dlManufacturer.Items.Add(new ListItem(ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Name"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["ManufacturerID"].ToString()));

                    x++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //failed to load models
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //invalid manufacturer
        }
    }
```

the exception is thrown at
     dlManufacturer.Items.Add(new ListItem(ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Name"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[x]["ManufacturerID"].ToString()));

I also tried

```
  //dlManufacturer.DataSource = ds;
                    //dlManufacturer.DataTextField = "Name";
                    //dlManufacturer.DataValueField = "ManufacturerID";
                    //dlManufacturer.DataBind();
```

but it too did not work, and like I mentioned before the spelling matches the column in Manufacturers Table.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

Your data table which you are binding with dropdownlist, doesn't contains the `ManufacturerID` column. Include this field into your select query and then try

```
SELECT Manufacturers.Name, Manufacturers.ManufacturerID 
FROM   Manufacturers INNER JOIN Products ON Manufacturers.ManufacturerID = Products.ManufacturerID
WHERE  Products.CategoryID = @category
```